# Watching CPU register

Tags: gcc

I'm new  with GCC using "Quincy 2005"

In Delphi or Borland C++ I can watch the value of any CPU register in "watch window" by simply adding the name of the register for (example "EAX")
to watch window list

but in "Quincy" this dose not work  (neither "EAX" or "%eax")
How do you trace the value of CPU registers in GCC ?

Comment: This question is probably better phrased as, "How do I use a debugger in this IDE?  Does it have one?"

Comment: Do you have any particular reason for using this IDE?

Comment: I'm looking for a free C++ compiler with IDE supporting inline "intel" assembly

Comment: Borland C++ is great, but is not free - Quincy is free with debugger, but hard to use inline assembly - I tried Visual Studio combined  with Mars C++  Compiler wich does perfect inline intel assembly support, but the IDE debugger does not match with the compiler, I did not tried GCC yet but it seems that it is weak in inline assembly.  Any idea ?